# Pass multiple values to JS function and back to c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

User clicks button, button loads JQuery Dialog box, User clicks 'delete' and 2 values are passed to DeleteInvoice() on WorkItemMgr.cs

```
 <input id="RemoveInvoice" type="button" value="Remove Invoice" onclick="ConfirmDeleteInvoice('<%:TempInvoiceId%>', '<%:InvoiceId %>')" />                                                           

        $("#RemoveInvoice").click(ConfirmDeleteInvoice);

        function ConfirmDeleteInvoice(InvoiceId, SiteIdentifier) {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 180,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Delete: function () {
                        WorkItemMgr.DeleteInvoice(InvoiceId, SiteIdentifier);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I have went through it with a breakpoint and the 2 correct values are being passed but getting an error with the `WorkItemMgr.DeleteInvoice(InvoiceId, SiteIdentifier);

Error: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DeleteInvoice'

DeleteInvoice is a webmethod...

```
[WebMethod]
protected string DeleteInvoice(int InvoiceId, int SiteIdentifier)
{
```

Comment: Going to have to call that web method with `$.ajax`

Comment: Did you add ScriptManager to the page? Take a look at this: http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx

Comment: You should really use signalR for this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, C# do supports variable arguments. According to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182366(v=vs.80).aspx the only thing you got to do is to add a vararg parameter and send it straight from your javascript function.

Hope it helps (: